# Filter feature doesn't work correctly with imported data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I import some data into my sheet using this script https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164 as JSON import is not supported natively

```
=ImportJSON("https://example.com/my-data?format=json")
```

The data is imported correctly and I can see it in my table.

I want to create a filter on this table to sort/filter columns.
But when I, for example, try to sort it in ascending order it doesn't work.
It kind of sorts it for a second but then it just returns to the initial state (I suppose it's because the `importJSON` function is taking over).

I tried copying the data to another sheet using
`=ArrayFormula(Sheet1!A:F)` and `={Sheet1!A:F}` formulas and sort it there, but it behaves the same.

**upd.** Also tried referencing the individual cells like `=Indirect("Sheet1!$E"&ROW())`

How to achieve the correct function for the filter feature in this case?

Comment: you cannot manually sort an array generated by a formula. You have two options: turn the array into a collection of single values using `INDEX` or use the `QUERY` function to do the sorting/filtering.

Comment: I made it work with `INDEX`, thanks.